# Generate dplyr arguments using values in another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data where the factor labels have been provided in separate files. As a result, when I read things in I have data that looks like this:

```
id <- seq(1,10,1)
factor_x <- as.factor(sample(x = 1:7, size = 10, replace = T))
data <- data.frame(id, factor_x)
```

And a separate data frame containing the labels for factor_x that looks like this:

```
code <- seq(1,7,1)
label <- letters[1:7]
factor_x_labels <- data.frame(code, label)
factor_x_labels$label <- as.character(factor_x_labels$label)
```

I am looking for an efficient way to update factor_x in data frame 'data' with the labels in data frame 'factor_x_labels'.

I have been trying to work with fct_recode from the forcats package or recode from dplyr but am running into trouble because (for example) the existing and updated labels need to be pasted as strings but need to separated by = as a symbol.

Comment: Outside of dplyr you could do this by just specifying the levels and labels from the other dataset - `factor(data$factor_x, levels=factor_x_labels$code, labels=factor_x_labels$label)`

Comment: Or with `match` ? `factor_x_labels$label[match(data$factor_x, factor_x_labels$code)]` ?

Comment: Thanks @thelatemail. I often forget about base R solutions. One issue is that sometimes there will be levels that I haven't been given a label for (e.g., in the example above, there might be values like -888 where there was missing data). Am I correct in thinking that in these cases the value will be coerced to NA?

Comment: Likewise re the base R solution, thanks also @Ronak Shah

Comment: I see I was late. @thelatemail's answer is nice and simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ronak comment is obviously working (and should maybe be an answer) but since this post was tagged `dplyr`, I'm also posting a `dplyr` solution:

```
factor_x_labels$code <- as.character(factor_x_labels$code) #this won't work if one of "code" and "factor_x" is numeric but not the other
data %>% 
  left_join(factor_x_labels, by=c("factor_x"="code")) %>% 
  rename(factor_x_label = label)
```